# d3 transition SVG polygon animation not smooth in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js, svg

I'm using d3 to animate an SVG polygon as follows...

https://jsfiddle.net/p6jy5t0n/35/

It's smooth on Chrome/Safari but horribly jerky on Firefox - the star even seems to dance around in terms of its positioning changing.

The code in question simply relies on chaining d3's transitions to make the star grow then shrink back to normal by increasing it's stroke-width...

```
d3.select(".svgStar").transition().duration(500).ease("easeElastic")
  .each("end",function(){
    d3.select(this).transition().duration(500).ease("easeElastic")
      .style("stroke-width","0.1px")
      .style("fill",starCol);
  })
  .style("stroke-width","2.5px")
  .style("fill","#fff400");
```

Any ideas what could be done to get a smoother transition in Firefox?

Comment: It's pretty smooth in Firefox for me. Maybe Firefox has software rendering turned on, versus hardware rendering?

Comment: Well, I tried it several times and I couldn't find any difference between Safari/Chrome and Firefox. Specify the FF version and OS as well *in the question* (not in the comments).

Comment: oh!  that's strange - it's smooth on Chrome and terrible on my Firefox

Comment: Firefox Quantum 64.0.2 on macOS Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: @d3wannabe coincidentally, that's **exactly** what I'm using. So, you have some strange problem somewhere else.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - cool, thanks for confirming.  I'll close this then since it doesn't seem very useful for anyone else!  edit: or maybe I'll keep it open since none of the close-options seemed to apply

Comment: You don't have a "strange problem". It happens the same for me: Firefox Quantum 64.0.2 on a Mac. Just saying: it's possible to animate the `stroke-width` with css

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with D3v5. The easeElastic behaves different in Chrome compared to D3v3.

Do you know what easeElastic does to the transition?

Try `d3.easeLinear` for comparision.

```js
function transformStar(){
  var starCol = d3.select(".svgStar").style("fill");
  var starAnimationDuration = 500;

  d3.select(".svgStar").style("stroke","rgb(255, 218, 93)");

  d3.select(".svgStar")
    .transition().duration(starAnimationDuration).ease(d3.easeElastic)
      .style("stroke-width","2.5px")
      .style("fill","#fff400")
    .transition().duration(starAnimationDuration).ease(d3.easeElastic)
      .style("stroke-width","0.1px")
      .style("fill",starCol);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="container">
  <svg>
    <g id="starG" style="transform:translateX(50px)">
      <polygon class="svgStar" fill="#ffda5d" stroke="none" w="9" cursor="default" points="94,20 101,43 125,43 106,58 113,80 94,66 74,80 80,58 62,43 86,43" style="transform: translate(-94px, 18px);">
      </polygon>
      <text x="0" y="74" id="starTxt" style="cursor: default; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; text-anchor: middle; fill: rgb(20, 171, 20); stroke-width: 0px;">
        Go!
      </text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
<button onclick="transformStar();">
  Transform Star!
</button>
```